# How to refresh an observable from another observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

First of all I am completely new to these technologies, so pardon me if the question sounds weird and the terminology is not appropriate.

I have component with some data presented in a table.

```
export class SourceFieldComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    componentState$: Observable<ComponentState<SourceFieldResponse>>;
    fileUploadState$: Observable<FileUploadState>;
    ...

    ngOnInit(): void {
      ...
      this.componentState$ = this.sourceFieldService.sourcesFieldsByDataSource$(this.dataSourceId)
            .pipe(
                map(response => {
                    this.currentData.next(response)
                    return { dataState: DataState.LOADED_STATE, appData: response }
                }),
                startWith({ dataState: DataState.LOADING_STATE, appData: null }),
                catchError((error: string) => {
                    return of({ dataState: DataState.ERROR_STATE, error: error })
                })
            );
       ...
    }


    onFileSelected(event) {
       ...
        this.fileUploadState$ = this.fileUploadService.uploadFile$(formData)
            .pipe(
                map(response => {
                    if (response.statusCode != this.RESPONSE_OK) {
                        return { uploadState: UploadState.ERROR_STATE, error: response.message }
                    }
                    return { uploadState: UploadState.LOADED_STATE, error: response.message }
                }),
                startWith({ uploadState: UploadState.LOADED_STATE }),
                catchError((error: string) => {
                    return of({ uploadState: UploadState.ERROR_STATE, error: error })
                })
            )
       ...
    }
}
```

When a new file is uploaded from the browser, the onFileSelected is called and the file is correctly uploaded to the backend.

Problem is that when the backend service responds I need to reload the table which shows the data (new records are created from the uploaded file).

I think that the componentState$ observable has to be 'refreshed' in some way but I don't really know hot to do that.

I tried something but apparently nothing works.

Comment: Hello Fab, the easy way is to move the componentState  logic  for a private method in the class, and then on the backend response, call again this method.
What do you think about that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have already tried some similar. When I call that method (which recreate this.componentState$) receiving the backend response, the backend is called another time (I ignore the reason!). The loop breaks because the backend error when inserting already existing records.

Answer (score 0):

This is one problem that can be solved with "Thinking Reactively". First of all I want to share 2 amazing talks on youtube, by Deborah Kurata and Ben Lesh (project lead of RxJS).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LKMwkuK0ZE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZYAph73mnI&t=966s

Now, let's get back into the solution.

The main topic of the solution is subject (https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) (other choice is behaviour subject, you can look it for yourself). The main point is, subject is observable-like object that can SUBSCRIBED TO and NEXT/ERROR/COMPLETE itself.

Here is the simplified solution in stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x6mb6v?file=src/app/app.component.ts